# Setting model parameter variation steps in lmfit

Tags: python, data-fitting

I need to fit a model's parameters to observational data, but the model's precision is low, and it isn't smooth relative to the parameters. I.e. when a parameter is changed only so slightly, the output values may remain the same.

Due to this fact, `lmfit` runs the model for a few rounds, variating the parameters, and then gives up. How can I specify the minimum parameter variation step so the changes it makes are actually meaningful? I'm currently using the `leastsq` method.

Comment: is it not possible to use some sort of a `for` loop that loops through a list of your parameters for each of the initial guess?

Comment: That's called "exhaustive search", and it's not a good option for big problems. This kind of software packages have been designed specially to optimize this task, and there's quite a bit of useful math involved to make things faster. So, no.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20478949/how-to-force-larger-steps-on-scipy-optimize-functions